# C#. Newline character in Xpath text()

Tags: xpath, text, newline

I've tried everything below, not working for me. I am trying to avoid using "contains"

```
//p[text()[contains(.,'text1')]][text()[contains(.,'text2')]]
```

Here is my html p element

```
<p>
  text1
  <br></br>
  text2
</p>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
"//p[normalize-space(text()) = 'text1text2']]"
"//p[normalize-space() = 'text1text2']]")
"//p[text()[normalize-space() ='text1text2']]"
"//p[text()[normalize-space().,'text1text2']]"
@"//p[text() = ""text1\r\ntext2""]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
"//p[.='text1text2']"
```

But I would still like to see if I could verify the newline in my xpath somehow.